# Mac won't boot: Way to mount drive and delete one file?

Tags: install, startup, crash, launchd

My macbook is currently a brick. I added a /etc/launchctl.conf file that must be malformed. The OS now crashes even when attempting to start in safe mode:

"launchd System bootstrapper has crashed: Seg fault"

I tried booting from a 10.6 boot CD but it just spun and spun. I have been able to boot an Ubuntu Live CD and mount the mac partition, but the hfsplus partition is always mounted read-only.

There must be an Apple utility I can use to get to a live terminal and delete this single file that is preventing my laptop from booting? If I can get the OSX install CD to boot will there be a utility that can help me?

Comment: One thing that I might try is using the OSX boot disk to run diskutil, which I think can disable journaling. Then from what I have read Linux should be able to mount the drive as writable.

Comment: Single user mode was the solution. I had tried Safe Mode earlier and when that didn't work I gave up on boot tricks thinking it was the lowest level I could boot in to. Thanks again Michael!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can boot into [single user mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_user_mode) by holding <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> at startup.

Single user mode starts you directly at the console, bypassing core Mac OS X startup processes. You should be able to remove or alter the offending file from there.

Comment: Thanks, that got me close, then "mount -o update /" to make the mount writable was the final step!

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget there's always Target Disk Mode, too. Start the Mac and hold down <kbd>T</kbd> until a Firewire icon appears - you now have the world's most expensive external hard drive. :) Plug into another Mac (or a Windows PC, maybe?) and you can access the hard drive on the machine in Target Disk Mode.

*(Note that this doesn't work on Macs without Firewire. Mac Book Air users, you're bang out of luck.)*

Comment: Cool! I imagine at least some drivers have to load for this to work, though?

Comment: Not sure about drivers, but the OS doesn't load so your changes to /etc/launchctl.conf won't get the chance to break anything.

Answer (score 0):

Start in single-user mode (like that other guy said). It'll say "If you wish to make modifications to files:" and give you two lines of commands. Type the second one, or type the first one for a File System Check, then press Enter. Then, if you want to delete a file (let's call it "brokenfile"), type (without quotes): "rm brokenfile", then press Enter.

Answer (score -1):

I used a Microsoft install disk erased my hard drive and started over. Problem solved for me. I already had what I needed backed up on an external harddrive.

Comment: How would a Microsoft install disk help a Macbook?