# Mac OSX Command-R Recovery Mode - "rm" is ineffective even in read/write mode?

Tags: software-update, recovery, bug, ios

I have a mac with low disk space, that failed to update, and displays an OSX install error on boot.  How can I delete some files, so the update can complete?

I can boot this in recovery mode with `Command-R`, the disk is 97% full.  However deleting files with `rm` does not change available disk space, though the files disappear.

I can run `/Volumes/OSX/usr/bin/du` to determine size of a directory, and I have found some large ones, but `rm -r` has the same problem, the space does not come back. Using `mount -u -w /Volumes/OSX` makes no difference and `lsof` is of no help. Is there a "trash can" concept at work?

I have read [Mac OSX Recovery Mode Terminal: rm -rf doesn't delete anything](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321117/mac-osx-recovery-mode-terminal-rm-rf-doesnt-delete-anything) and it is not quite on point, and the ideas there do not apply.

```
Filesystem   512-blocks       Used Available Capacity  iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1    3932080    2485720   1407040    64%    45155          4294922124    0%   /
devfs               411        411         0   100%      712                   0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk3        10240        952      9288    10%       20          4294967259    0%   /private/var/log
/dev/disk18       12288        344     11944     3%        2          4294967277    0%   /private/var/tmp/RecoveryTemp
/dev/disk19       12288        344     11944     3%        2          4294967277    0%   /private/var/tmp/OSISPredicateUpdateProductTemp
/dev/disk20        1024        280       744    28%        2          4294967277    0%   /private/var/tmp/InstallerCookies
/dev/disk21        4096        280      3816     7%        2          4294967277    0%   /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
/dev/disk2s1  499708512  478105512  16094888    97%  1954820 9223372036852820987    0%   /Volumes/OSX
/dev/disk4s1 1462037904 1442425824  19612080    99% 14394174          4280573105    0%   /Volumes/Backup1
/dev/disk4s2  491487192  162467080 329020112    34%    53008          4294914271    0%   /Volumes/Backup2
```

What can I do to get this machine back?

Comment: Which specific files are you trying to `rm`? Are the actually deleted or do they still show up with `ls` afterwards?

Comment: I've deleted a few old movies, and directories of old user files.  They do not show up with `ls` afterward, they do not show up after reboot.

Comment: Why does this need to be done in Recovery?  Couldn’t you just get a USB drive, move your files that you want to archive to it and delete them from your disk?

Comment: @Allan "mac ... displays an OSX install error on boot"

Comment: Sometimes a failed update can be bypassed by holding Option while booting and selecting the main OS drive again.  What about running "/sbin/mount -uw /" (not /Volumes/OSX)? Other options, if you have another mac handy... connect the machine in target disk mode and deleting data?  Or make a bootable macos usb, start from that, and delete files from the hard drive?

Comment: I don't have another mac, else I'd get a USB to SATA adapter, and delete the files that way.  In recovery mode / appears to be the read only recovery image, and /Volumes/OSX is the original unmodified hard drive.

Comment: @nohillside - *"Displays an OS X install error on boot" ≠ "doesn't boot."*  I'm still not clear as to whether the system boots or not.  This entire problem also sounds a bit odd - I've never known a macOS install update to even proceed if there wasn't enough disk space.

Comment: This statement is very unclear:  *Using `mount -u -w /Volumes/OSX` makes no difference...*  This makes *all* the difference.  When you boot into recovery, you're mounting a completely different disk/partition.  Unless you mount it, you won't be able to do anything to/with it.  Can you please expand on what you mean by "it makes you difference?"