# How can I remove files while in Recovery Mode?

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, macos

[image]The problem I have is to do with having a full disk and not being able to complete the reboot.

I can get to running diskutil list on Terminal. However then I can get nowhere else and I can not get also details of the virtual machine from Terminal.

It would be great, if anybody could advise please, how to delete files using Terminal in a recovery mode, so that I could hopefully get past the reboot bit.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321117/mac-osx-recovery-mode-terminal-rm-rf-doesnt-delete-anything?rq=1 might give some pointers. What have you tried in terms of deleting files? What does `diskutil list; df -h` show (take a picture and add it to the question)?

Comment: Thank you, @nohillside, just loaded the picture of diskutil list output, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. `df -h` as well, if possible.

Comment: Thank you, @nohillside, just added df -h output too

Comment: `mkdir /Volumes/mac; mount /dev/disk0s2 /Volumes/mac` should mount your main disk.

Comment: Thank you, nohillside! I have just run this and now get this error message, please see attached a new picture

Comment: Well, I was eventually able to mount disk0s2 :-) at least I have received the message that “Volume(s) successfully mounted”. Any suggestions please on what and how I can delete now safely to free up some space?

Comment: Your own files should be in /Volumes/mac/Users/YOURACCOUNT, delete whatever makes sense. I assume you have a backup.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. At the moment I am struggling with the next bit, trying to find out what is the name of my account..tried different ways, including whoami, ls /users..none gives me an answer unfortunately

Comment: Try `ls /Volumes/Mac/Users`

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have tried so far all that was suggested and can not get anywhere yet with releasing space. I wonder, if there is any safe way of releasing space in Terminal? Maybe by removing everything from Trash, as I know that I should have had there some files, that will be occupying space. However unfortunately, none of the code lines I write are achieving any goal, they are either giving error messages or do not change the space volume. Any suggestions please, guys?

Comment: Please add the things you tried to the question (take pictures if necessary). We have no way of knowing what you did and what possible could have gone wrong without you showing us what you did.

Comment: Thank you, @nohillside, I have now added the most recent sufferings of mine with mounting the disk0s2. I have succeeded with this eventually. I would appreciate any further help in finding how to remove safely some unnecessary  files, for example all files in Trash, cookies history etc.etc. Any pointers on how to write this exactly in Terminal will be highly appreciated. All I am trying to do is to release some space from completely filled up disk, so that  I can complete the reboot if he system. I have a backup, however would like to use this option last, as the backup is not most up to date.

Comment: Run `df -h` again to see where disk0s2 got mounted, then `cd WHEREVER-IT-IS-MOUNTED; ls -l Users`. This should show you the accounts you have. Use cd again to go into the appropriate directory, then start to remove files.

Comment: If something doesn’t work, stop and add another screenshot. You are our eyes here, we can only help you as far as you show us what‘s happening.

Comment: Thank you, @nohillside. I was just recently reunited with my laptop again. Now back to trying to solve the same issue - any help, as always, will be greatly appreciated. I added just now the picture with the steps I have taken so far. At loss what to do after in order to release any reasonable space - for example, from Trash.

Comment: Screenshots are a bit a mess right now, it's hard to understand in which state the system currently is. But try `cd /Volumes/?ac/Users; ls -l`. (The ? is intentional).

Comment: Sorry about the screenshots, I have to take pictures on the phone and upload it this way. I have tried and now added new screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally lost about the state your system is in. Please redo the steps you took last time and mount the data volume under /Volumes/Mac.

Comment: Sure, I added another screenshot  - unable to find the disk.

Comment: Well, you didn't specify a disk to mount in the first place, just the directoy it should get mounted to.

Comment: Sorry, did you mean to use diskutil mountDisk /Volumes/Mac/disk0s2;? I tried this now, get unable to find disk for /Volumes/Mac/disk0s2

Comment: You seemed to have been able to mount the disk in the past. Please look through your notes (if you took some) or through the screenshots in the post, it is most likely in there.

Comment: Yes, this logic works fine and mounts the disk0s2 - diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk0s2; I used the same logic but with /Volumes/Mac/disk0s2 and this fails.

Comment: If the disk is already mounted, on which directory got it mounted?

Comment: Please run `diskutil list; mount`, remove all the screenshots from the question and just add one showing the output of this.

Comment: Sure, added a screenshot. The successfully mounted disk is disk 0s2, however it is not in the list of mount  output.

Comment: /dev/disk0s2 is definitively not mounted. Can you get local help by somebody who knows how to do this? It’s rather difficult without access to the machine.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! ☺️ I have given up and restored using Time Machine.